# Is there a reliable chemical theory that predicts pKa based on structure?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, theoretical-chemistry

Obviously, there are general stability arguments that can be made to estimate relative pKas, such as evaluating the stability of the conjugate base of an acid, or thinking about how polarized the bond to hydrogen is.

However, is there a theory that can be absolute and account for the many exceptions to the above guidelines? What are the factors that are preventing a rigorous theory from being proposed?

Comment: Unfortunately acid/base strengths are still major weak points in quantum theory; there are no rigorous and affordable theories or approximations available. Most approaches have to be calibrated against highly accurate experimental measurements.

Comment: This 2015 review article is behind a paywall, but its abstract seems to provide a good summary of the state of the field, namely that it continues to be an active area of research, and there are two basic approaches researchers are pursing:  https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/wcms.1218

Comment: @theorist the article you mention *is* available to the public, either on request on research gate (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274141867_Computational_estimation_of_pKa_values) or directly and freely (no paywall), e.g., http://mercuryconsortium.org/furman/pubs/SeyboldsS2015.pdf

Comment: thanks for the responses, I talked to Seybold, and it seems that using rigorous quantum chemical calculations is too computationally expensive. It is the solvent effects and the corresponding entropy changes that make things complicated really fast.

Comment: @NathanMatthieuTang It would be great if you could summarize the comments and your conversation with Seybold in an answer to your own question.

Comment: @KarstenTheis, Seybold wrote: "The central problem in predicting pKas comes from the difficulty in accounting for the interactions between the acid compounds and the surrounding solvent.  Gas phase acidities, which are described in terms of delta Gs, can be rather accurately estimated if one applies sufficiently advanced quantum techniques. But solution acidity computations, which usually rely on continuum approximations for the solvent, aren't really up to the challenge.  Remember that one now must account for thermodynamic alterations in both the solute compound and the surrounding solvent."

Comment: @NathanMatthieuTang I would again encourage you to summarize comments and the quote in an answer. Eventually, someone else will probably write one, but you should get credit for your own research.

Comment: Somewhat surprising that this hasn't been linked here: [Calculating pKa's using Gaussian](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/70447/4945)